# How to add ratelimit rule for forgot password in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rate-limiting

Basically I want a ratelimit rule for forgot password to protect it from overuse. How to add rules in firestore.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Firestore has yet to implement rate limiting through security rules.

link: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/647

At this time you can rate limit by having the user access features through cloud functions and frontend.

Example:

- Use frontend properties to limit using the 'forgot password' link. I.e. use a counter to show/hide the forgot password link
- Fingerprint the user and rate limit based on activity
- Incorporate rate limit features in a Cloud Function. I.e. a user clicks 'Forgot Password' and triggers a cloud function that will/will not send the Forgot Password email based on your criteria